# Problem accessing variables before they are defined

Tags: java, initialization

I have this:

```
public class Sprite

{
    protected float x;
    protected float y;
    protected Image image;
    protected Rectangle boundingBox;


    public Rectangle getBoundingBox()
    {
         boundingBox = new Rectangle(x, y,
                    image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        return boundingBox;
    }
```

However I get a null pointer exception when I run it. The class sprite is never used by itself, only used as a superclass.

The only way for image to be defined is through the constructor:

```
Sprite(float x, float y, Image image) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.image = image;
}
```

Comment: You get a null pointer where? Please post the error message itself (or at least show us which line is generating the error). Your code example doesn't even include the code that calls this (where the instance would theoretically be instantiated). If Sprite is only used as a superclass, you've got to show us which line, in the sub-class, is throwing the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably because the variable `image` is never initialized. Therefore `image.getWidth()` and `image.getHeight()` will fail with `NullPointerException`s. Either initialize the variable. Or pass in `image` or check for `null` before you attempt to use it.

Comment: Aye, but the only way for it to be initialised is through the constructor.

Comment: Then do a null check before you attempt to use it and then handle appropriately (perhaps a lazy load to a default or throw an exception etc). If you leave nulls to chance, they will happen.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting a `NullPointerException` because `image` hasn't been initialized.

**EDIT:**

> The class sprite is never used by itself, only used as a superclass.
>   The only way for image to be defined is through the constructor:

I'm not sure I understand your aversion to using a constructor. If `Sprite` is being used as a superclass, then it's used just as much as if it was used by itself - so it needs to be fully baked.

Answer (score 2):

```
protected Image image;
```

needs to be initialized if you want to get its width and height.